# Laravel apply ordering to withAggregate clause

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have the following query:

```
$users = \App\Models\User::withAggregate('lastactivity', 'created_at')
    ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
    ->paginate(15);
```

Which translates to:

```
select `users`.*, (select created_at from `users_activity` where `users`.`id` = `users_activity`.`user_id` limit 1) as `lastactivity_created_at` from `users` order by `id` desc limit 15 offset 0
```

How can I order the `lastactivity` by descending? Otherwise I'm always getting the first result.

**Expected result**:

```
select `users`.*, (select created_at from `users_activity` where `users`.`id` = `users_activity`.`user_id` order by id desc limit 1) as `lastactivity_created_at` from `users` order by `id` desc limit 15 offset 0
```

The users model has the following relationship:

```
public function lastactivity(): HasOne
{
    return $this->hasOne(UsersActivity::class)->orderBy('id', 'DESC');
}
```

But even though I'm applying the order in the relationship, the `withAggregate` function ignores it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you have `hasOne` relation on `UsersActivity` class. That's why order doesn't apply to query.

[Try to use latestOfMany](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-of-many)

```
public function lastactivity(): HasOne
{
    return $this->hasOne(UsersActivity::class)->latestOfMany();
}
```